# How to put a waved line under misspelled words HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage HTML & JS.

I need to add a red waved-line under misspelled  words.
I got my algorithm to detect those words but I just need to know how put a waved line under those words.

Comment: Do you mean misspelled?

Comment: Why a waved line?   Why not a thick dashed line, just like every other program?

Comment: @Sparky672 because most programs use waved lines?

Comment: @Timo:  With the exception of Word, "most" programs on my computer are using a red dotted line... but most people wouldn't notice that subtle difference.

Comment: As of Oct/2023, browsers support this natively via the [text-decoration-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style) CSS property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually you don't have a standard curly underline just by using CSS, but check this tutorial on how to create one yourself:

Taken from here: http://www.phpied.com/curly-underline/

```
.curly-underline {
    background: url(underline.gif) bottom repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

If you don't wanna use a gif for the curly underline, you can do it by pure css:

```html
<span style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0000;padding:1px">
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0000;">
        foobar
    </span>
</span>
```

(Or run in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQfw8/))

Answer (score 15):

Red, wavy underline is very simple, as specified in CSS 3's [Text Decoration Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-style).

```css
* { text-decoration: underline wavy red; }
```

```html
Run me in Chrome or Firefox to see me ride over a red wave!
```

Browser support is catching up.
You may [vote for it](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6514536-text-decoration-styling) for Microsoft Edge, which I would encourage you to do.

The spec is not new; Firefox has been supporting it [since 2011](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style#Browser_compatibility), and Chrome since 2016.
Hopefully, we can count on Safari and Edge to support it soon too.

Update 2017: Chrome has closed the issue in 2016, and I've tested it with Chrome 58, which works, and is a big boost of the wavy lines.

Comment: It looks terrible on Chrome, even the dotted solution looks better. Can't they learn from 1980s Microsoft Word?