# Is it possible to make a squiggly line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

If I wanted to make a horizontal line, I would do this:

```
<style>
#line{
    width:100px;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#000;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="line"></div>
```

If I wanted to make a vertical line, I would do this:

```
#line{
    width:1px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="line"></div>
```

A curved line is trickier, but possible using `border-radius` and wrapping the element:

```
<style>
.curve{
    width:100px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    border-radius:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:40px;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="curve"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

But I cannot even fathom how I could generate squiggly lines! **Is this even remotely possible using only css (and javascript since it does seem that it will be necessary to be able to more easily generate them).**

## note:

As expected, given your answers there is no way to do this in sole css...javascript and jquery are 100 percent okay for your answer...**NO IMAGES CAN BE USED**

Comment: a couple of `.curve` elements stuck together?

Comment: How about using [CSS3 border images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)?

Comment: You might be able to so something like this using multiple div's set next to each other with a very high border-radius.  You'd also have to hide the top/ bottom halves of the elements depending on if they were odd or even which you can do with CSS.

Comment: Why no images? Not even SVG?

Comment: @david because the application I am using this for will have the user create the squiggle

Comment: Just to note that technology changes -- the current selected answer is probably no longer valid. For anyone stumbling upon this as I did, refer to MDN `text-decoration-style:wavy` > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This question is fairly old, but I found a way to do with without Javascript, repetitive CSS or images.

You can use background-size to define the size, and then repeat it with linear-gradient.

I put a bunch of examples here: http://jsbin.com/hotugu/edit?html,css,output

[image: example]

The basic gist is:

```css
.holder {
  /* Clip edges, as some of the lines don't terminate nicely. */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.ellipse {
  position: absolute;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse, transparent, transparent 7px, black 7px, black 10px, transparent 11px);
  background-size: 36px 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
}

.ellipse2 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 18px;
  background-position: 0px -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="ellipse"></div>
  <div class="ellipse ellipse2"></div>
</div>
```

You can produce squiggly lines with some modifications:

```css
.holder {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 25px;
}
.tinyLine {
    position: absolute;
    /* Cuts off the bottom half of the pattern */
    height: 20px;
    /* For better cross browser consistency, make it larger with width.  */
    width: 1000%;
    /* And then scale it back down with scale, recentering with translateX. */
    transform: translateX(-45%) scale(0.1);
}

.tinyLine1 {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
}
.tinyLine2 {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
}
.tinyLine {
    /* Must be after background definition. */
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="tinyLine tinyLine1"></div>
    <div class="tinyLine tinyLine2"></div>
</div>
```

The browser support is reasonable (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients), IE 10 will probably work, however things break down at small scales in different browsers. If you want it to work on really small scales consistently you may want to make the line on a larger scale and then scale it down with `transform: scale(x);`.

It should also be very fast, as linear-gradients are rendered on the GPU in all major browsers.

Comment: This is ingenious! I needed a way to simulate `text-decoration: underline wavy red;` cross-browser, and managed to adapt this answer and use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to get a workable substitute. Thanks!

Comment: Just use decoration:wavy now => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style

Comment: For the first demo, how did you arrive at the background size width being 36px?

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:**  Given the requirement of no images/data uri.

You can also cram a bunch of border-radius elements together, alternating with top/bottom or left/right edges disabled. I've generalized this into a function that appends them to an element.

Javascript, where squigglecount is the number of "squiggles". You could generalize that to an actual width if you so desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/V7QEJ/1/

```js
function makeLine(id, squiggleCount) {
  var curve;
  var lineEl = $(id);

  for (var i = 0; i < squiggleCount; i++) {
    curve = document.createElement('div');
    curve.className = 'curve-1';
    lineEl.append(curve);

    curve = document.createElement('div');
    curve.className = 'curve-2';
    lineEl.append(curve);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    makeLine('#line', 16);
});
```

```css
.curve-1,
.curve-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.curve-1 {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.curve-2 {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line">
</div>
```

**Old (with images):**

There's already a bunch of answers, but here's an easy way to do a vertical squiggly line, similar to Lawson's answer.

Basically, you use background-image and a data-uri of a squiggly line to do it. I probably wouldn't use this for anything but it's an interesting thought exercise. There are a bunch of data uri generators that you can use online to change your own images.

http://jsfiddle.net/zadP7/

```css
.aux{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.line{
    display: inline-block;
    
    height: 400px;
    width: 10px;
    
    background-image:       url(data:image/png;base64,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);   
}
```

```html
<div class="aux">Stuff</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="aux">More Stuff</div>
```

Comment: I added an alternative solution that does not use images if that would be of any additional help to you.

Comment: That answer is the best yet, although can only work repetitively, it gives a lot of room! I'll accept it since a complicated, non repeating squiggle can clearly only be done with an image after seeing these answers

Answer (score 10):

If you want the underline of some text to be a squiggly line, you can use the following css:

```css
span {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Example text here</span>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line#example

Answer (score 8):

### Pure CSS solution:

We can use the [sin wave character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/223f/index.htm) '∿' character and then

Set a negative value for `letter-spacing`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/e4buLow2/7/)**

[image]

Just for fun we can use different characters to get other squiggles:

**[FIDDLE #2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/e4buLow2/6/)**

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
.tilde {
  letter-spacing: -19px;
}
.ohm {
  letter-spacing: -6px;
}
.ac {
  letter-spacing: -25px;
}
.acd {
  letter-spacing: -11px;
}
.curlyv {
  letter-spacing: -12px;
}
.frown {
  letter-spacing: -13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="acd">∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿∿</div>
<div class="tilde">˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜</div>
<div class="curlyv">⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎⋎</div>
<div class="frown">⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢⌢</div>
<div class="ac">∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾∾</div>
<div class="ohm">ΩΩΩΩΩΩΩΩΩΩ</div>
```

Comment: sin wave &#8767; curlyv &#8910; ohm &#937; frown &#65077; the following works with letter spacing 0 - &#65103; (Wavy Low Line) ﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏

Comment: Which common fonts can I rely on to have these characters? I'm concerned that the letter spacing would have to be different depending which font the browser uses. On my system, at least, Verdana is used as specified for the tilde, but fallback fonts are used for the wavy low line and the sine wave characters.

Comment: This is really neat but I wouldn't recommend ever using it in the real world because of font differences.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not looking for something really neat, but just for the fun of it, play with multiple box-shadow:
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/mfGdp or http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/xhqFu

```
.curve{
  margin:3em 0;
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:
    0px 2px 1px -1px,
    400px 0px 0px 0px white,
    400px 2px 1px -1px ,
    300px 0px 0px 0px white,
    300px -2px 1px -1px,
    600px 0px 0px 0px white,
    600px 2px 1px -1px ,
    500px 0px 0px 0px white,
    500px -2px 1px -1px,
    800px 0px 0px 0px white,
    800px 2px 1px -1px ,
    700px 0px 0px 0px white,
    700px -2px 1px -1px,
    1000px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1000px 2px 1px -1px ,
    900px 0px 0px 0px white,
    900px -2px 1px -1px,
    1200px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1200px 2px 1px -1px ,
    1100px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1100px -2px 1px -1px,
    1400px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1400px 2px 1px -1px ,
    1300px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1300px -2px 1px -1px,
    1600px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1600px 2px 1px -1px ,
    1500px 0px 0px 0px white,
    1500px -2px 1px -1px;
  position:relative;
}
.curve:before,.curve:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border-radius:100%;
  box-shadow:inherit;
}
.curve:before {
  left:100%;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
 }
.curve:after {
  left:200%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏﹏

& #65103 ; (wavy low line)

I hope this is not too much off topic - here is how to use those squiggly lines to underline some text (should be a common use case.)

method 1 (snatched from Wulf answering a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821365/how-to-put-a-waved-line-under-misspelled-words-html))

```
<span style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0000;padding:1px">
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff0000;">
        foobar
    </span>
</span>
```

(not really a squiggly line but a collection of dots, but looks OK and is beautifully simple.)

method 2 (inspired by DanieldD)

using & #65103 ; (wavy low line) unicode character and absolute / relative positioning to put that character underneath some text. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/moromigumi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

here is "the meat" of the code for the positioning

```
function performUnderWavyLowLineazation(contentElt){
    var wavyFontSize = 40;
    var width = contentElt.width();
    contentElt.addClass("underWavyLowLined");
    replaceSpaceByNonBreakingSpace(contentElt);
    var sp = "<span/>";
    var wrapper = contentElt.wrap(sp).parent();
    wrapper.addClass("wavyParent");
    var underlining = jQuery(sp, {"class" : "wavyLowLine"}).prependTo(wrapper);
    var ghost;
    var invisibleGhostThatTakesUpTheSpaceThatUnderWavyLowLinedElementShouldTakeButDoesntDueToBeingAbsolute
        = ghost = jQuery(sp, {"class": "invisibleUnderWavyLowLined"}).appendTo(wrapper);
    ghost.html(contentElt.html());
    ghost.find("*").removeAttr("id");
    replaceSpaceByNonBreakingSpace(ghost);
    var numWavyChars = Math.floor(0.1 + width/wavyFontSize);
    innerUnderLine = jQuery(sp, {"class": "innerWaveLine"}).appendTo(underlining);
    innerUnderLine.html("&#65103;".repeat(numWavyChars));
    var lineLength = wavyFontSize * numWavyChars;
    var defect = width - lineLength;
    innerUnderLine.css("left", defect/2);
    var wavyGroup = jQuery(sp, {"class" : "wavyGroup"}).prependTo(wrapper);
    underlining.appendTo(wavyGroup);
    contentElt.appendTo(wavyGroup);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank [@yeerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1117119/yeerk) for such a wonderful solution!

But I would like to suggest some improvements to his first variants — to those of waves what seem to be more triangular. I would suggest to use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements instead of hard-coded enclosed divs.

It may look like this (html):

```
<div class="triangly-line"></div>
```

— where `triangly-line` is a target decorated element (not "waved" but "triangled").

Corresponding styles (using LESS notation) will look like this:

```
@line-width: 300px;
@triangled-size: 6px;
@triangly-color: red;
@double-triangled-size: (@triangled-size * 2 - 1px);
.linear-gradient (@gradient) {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@gradient);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(@gradient);
    background: linear-gradient(@gradient);
}
.triangly-gradient (@sign, @color) {
    .linear-gradient(~"@{sign}45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, @{color} 49%, transparent 51%");
}
.triangly-line {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: @triangled-size;
    &:before {
        .triangly-gradient("", @triangly-color);
    }
    &:after {
        .triangly-gradient("-", @triangly-color);
    }
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: @line-width;
        height: @triangled-size;
        background-size: @double-triangled-size @double-triangled-size !important;
    }
}
```

Resulted CSS (using specified above parameters):

```
.triangly-line {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 6px;
}
.triangly-line:before {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
}
.triangly-line:after {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 49%, red 49%, transparent 51%);
}
.triangly-line:before,
.triangly-line:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 6px;
    background-size: 11px 11px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a slighty nicer way to achieve trangle squiggly lines in CSS without halving heights or applying tricks that don't work well across browsers.

[image: result]

I tried [@yeerk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764538/3984876) but it only works well in Chrome. The lines had artifacts on Safari and Firefox.

**Firefox**

[image: firefox artifacts]

**Safari**

[image: safari artifact]

This solution is a variation of [@liliputen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501455/3984876), however it improves on ease of flexibility.

You can change the line's size easily from the `background-size` property.

```css
.squiggly {
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.squiggly::after,
.squiggly::before {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    background-size: 12px 100%; /* Change this to adjust the size of the squiggly line. */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}

.squiggly::before {
    top: -2px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 35%, transparent 0),
        linear-gradient(-45deg, red 35%, transparent 0);
}

.squiggly::after {
    top: 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 35%, transparent 0),
        linear-gradient(-45deg, white 35%, transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="squiggly"></div>
```

You can also find it here on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/appcypher/wxrvm5uy/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the border, use a tiled background image.

I do not think there is a solution that get's away without using a graphics file and that also works in all browsers.

If you are brave you can try this:http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/

It allows to draw on the canvas in HTML5, but it would not work on older browsers.

if you can add a lot of html you can use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/QsM4J/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>
    before
    </p>
    <div id="sqig">
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="topsqig"><div></div></div>
        <div class="bottomsqig"><div></div></div>
    </div>
    <p>
    after
    </p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#sqig{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:6px;
}
#sqig div{
    position:relative;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 0 0 -4px;
    padding:0;    
}
#sqig .topsqig div{
    border-radius: 3px;
    top:1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
#sqig .bottomsqig div{
    border-radius: 3px;
    top:-1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I will look into html canvas...seems as I can give it a graph, which I would rather not have to come up with an equation, but it could be the only way...and I can't use an image

Comment: Well, that is rather unfortunate, but somehow that link was for an old version... Anyways, I updated the link in the post to point to the new version: http://jsfiddle.net/QsM4J/

Answer (score 0):

Before there was HTML5 and Canvas, there was [JavaScript VectorGraphics](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm). You may want to give it a try if you want to draw  Circles, Ellipses etc. etc. in pure HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SASS wave line generator based on the answer from [@yeerk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764538/5950626). If you want triangles, use the generator above by [@lilliputten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501455/5950626).

```
$waveHeight: 40px;
$waveLength: 70px;
$waveRadius: 13px; // adjust depending on length
$waveThickness: 8px;

@mixin waveSide() {
  position: absolute;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse, transparent, transparent $waveRadius, black $waveRadius, black #{$waveRadius + $waveThickness}, transparent #{$waveRadius + $waveThickness});
  background-size: #{$waveLength} #{$waveHeight * 2};
  height: $waveHeight;
}

.wavy {
  width: 400px; // give the wave element a length here

  @include waveSide;

  &::before {
    $waveOffset: $waveLength / 2;
    @include waveSide;

    content: '';
    width: calc(100% - #{$waveOffset});
    top: $waveHeight;
    left: $waveOffset;
    background-position: 0px -#{$waveHeight};
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Javascript, this can be easily achieved using a sine wave - this is how programming languages have achieved controllable squiggly lines for decades!  You should be able to find plenty of examples out there, but essentially you just do loop with an incrementing x value and apply the sine function sin().  This used to be cool for doing screen-savers in the 90s and animating them, etc.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Here is how to make an SVG animated using SMIL:

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     width="768"
     viewBox="12 0 744 114"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <rect x="12" width="372" height="128"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <path d="m764 23c-8 10-8-10-16 0s-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0"
          fill="none" stroke="#bbc133" stroke-width="3">
      <animateTransform
              type="translate"
              attributeName="transform"
              from="0 0"
              to="-16 0"
              begin="0s"
              dur="2s"
              fill="remove"
              repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
    <path d="m764 64c-8 10-8-10-16 0s-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0c-8 9-8-9-16 0s-8-9-16 0c-8 8-8-8-16 0s-8-8-16 0c-8 7-8-7-16 0s-8-7-16 0c-8 6-8-6-16 0s-8-6-16 0c-8 5-8-5-16 0s-8-5-16 0c-8 4-8-4-16 0s-8-4-16 0c-8 3-8-3-16 0s-8-3-16 0c-8 2-8-2-16 0s-8-2-16 0c-8 1-8-1-16 0s-8-1-16 0h-16-16-16-16"
          fill="none" stroke="#7cb32f" stroke-width="3">
      <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="translate"
              from="0 0"
              to="-16 0"
              dur="2s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="remove"
              repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
    <path d="m764 105c-8 10-8-10-16 0s-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0"
          fill="none" stroke="#2ca84a" stroke-width="3">
      <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="translate"
              from="0 0"
              to="-16 0"
              dur="2s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="remove"
              repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <animate
              values="
                  m764 105c-8 10-8-10-16 0s-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0;
                  m764 105c-8 0-8 0-16 0s-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0-8 0-16 0;
                  m764 105c-8 10-8-10-16 0s-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0-8-10-16 0"
              attributeName="d"
              dur="4s"
              begin="0s"
              fill="remove"
              repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </g>
  <path d="m384 23h372" fill="none" stroke="#bbc133" stroke-opacity="0.23921569" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="m384 64h372" fill="none" stroke="#7cb32f" stroke-opacity="0.23921569" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"/>
  <path d="m384 105h372" fill="none" stroke="#2ca84a" stroke-opacity="0.23921569" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"/>
  <circle cx="384" cy="23" r="9" fill="#bbc133"/>
  <circle cx="384" cy="64" r="9" fill="#7cb32f"/>
  <circle cx="384" cy="105" r="9" fill="#2ca84a"/>
</svg>
```

There is also [this library for Kotlin (Android)](https://github.com/mahozad/wavy-slider) with an online [demo](https://mahozad.ir/wavy-slider).