# Wavy line background on link hover

Tags: css

I've tried a few work arounds to this and I'm struggling! I have some menu items that, when on the current page, the menu ancestor has a border-bottom indicating current.

I want this line to be wavy, instead. I've tried `text-decoration-style: wavy` but it's not supported across browsers and it puts the wavy line in front of the text, blocking legibility. This nearly has the look I'm going for, though!

I've also tried an SVG but as each of these lines are different colors (I know, this gets more complex...), I don't want to have so many different images being called by my browser.

Now I'm trying the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285514/is-it-possible-to-make-a-squiggly-line). I just can't figure out how to get :before and :after to work...pseudo-classes are new to me. Any ideas?

Here's my wavy line-through so far. I want a wave behind the text instead.

[image]

**Edit:**

CSS:

```
.menu-hover-style-2 .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-11853.current-menu-item > a.menu-item-link, .menu-hover-style-2 .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-11853.current-menu-ancestor > a.menu-item-link {
color: #000000!important;
text-decoration-line: line-through;
text-decoration-color: #e23d75!important;
text-decoration-style: wavy;
display: block;
}
```

I'm working on a WP site with a template so there's no hard-coded HTML.

Previously, I had:

```
`border-bottom: 2px #e23d75 solid;
line-height: 9px;`
```

Or something to that effect.

**EDIT** I've gotten it mostly working, but now I have a gap where the `:before` isn't flush with the `:after`.

```
.menu-hover-style-2 .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-43.current-menu-item > a.menu-item-link, .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-43.current-menu-ancestor > a.menu-item-link {
color: #000000!important;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}


.menu-hover-style-2 .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-43.current-menu-item > a.menu-item-link:before, .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-43.current-menu-ancestor > a.menu-item-link:before {
position: absolute;
background: radial-gradient(ellipse, transparent, transparent 4px, #f0b49e 4px, #f0b49e 6px, transparent 6px);
background-size: 20px 18px;
width: 200px;
height: 9px;
content: "";
top: 30px;
z-index: -1;
}

.menu-hover-style-2 .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-43.current-menu-item > a.menu-item-link:after, .main-navigation-ul > li#menu-item-43.current-menu-ancestor > a.menu-item-link:after {
position: absolute;
background: radial-gradient(ellipse, transparent, transparent 4px, #f0b49e 4px, #f0b49e 6px, transparent 6px);
background-size: 20px 18px;
width: 200px;
height: 9px;
top: 39px;
left: 2px;
background-position: 8px -10px;
content: "";
z-index: -1;
}
```

[image: Home with wavy line]

Comment: Could you provide CSS and HTML ? And what you want exactly, thanks

Comment: @LPK Added above!

Comment: You have an example here for the `:before` and `:after` use : http://jsfiddle.net/jAXXA

Comment: @LPK Okay, I've got a version of it going using `:before` and `:after` now. I've got a little gap where the `:before` doesn't start flush with the `:after` though....I've edited above.

Comment: Figured it out. A simple and very obvious `left: 0px;` fixes the gap issue for the `:before` psudo-element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use in this way with before and after

```css
.nav-item{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: red;
}

.nav-item:before {
    position: absolute;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse, transparent, transparent 7px, black 7px, black 10px, transparent 11px);
    background-size: 36px 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    top: 35px;
}

.nav-item:after {
    position: absolute;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse, transparent, transparent 7px, black 7px, black 10px, transparent 11px);
    background-size: 36px 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 53px;
    left: 18px;
    background-position: 0px -20px;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="nav-item">About</h1>
```

Comment: Okay, I've just about got it, but it looks like the `:before` starts shifted over to the right of the `:after`. It's also much wider than the text it's under, which the width is going to change from menu ancestor to menu ancestor. (http://www.melanie-patterson.com)