# A wavy underline in CSS

Tags: html, css, underline

Can I create a wavy underline as this : [image: http://i.imgur.com/aiBjQry.png]
I can only get a solid border :

```css
.err {
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>A boy whose name was Peter was <div class="err">woking</div> down the street</div>
```

Comment: Try this: http://www.phpied.com/curly-underline/

Comment: check out `border-image` property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)

Comment: As of Oct/2023, browsers support this natively via the [text-decoration-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style) CSS property.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Without background image:**

```css
.err {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.err:before {
  content: "~~~~~~~~~~~~";
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Times New Roman, Serif;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>A boy whose name was Peter was
  <div class="err">woking</div> down the street</div>
```

**With Background image :**

```css
.err {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/HlfA2is.gif) bottom repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div>A boy whose name was Peter was <div class="err">woking</div> down the street</div>
```

Comment: That's very tricky… haha. You should use a background image to have the same effect on every browser.

Comment: For longer words this wouldn't work very well, you would have to put an overflow on it and make the content very big. But I like the idea.

Comment: It also depends on the font family… if the user have Georgia or Arial by default set in his browser, your solution is not working anymore. That needs typo fixes. Not the best idea I think.

Comment: I have changed font-family to Times New Roman, which is available on almost every computer.

Comment: For such a small image, the data scheme may be preferred 
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhBAADAPEAANv///8AAP///wAAACwAAAAABAADAEACBZQjmIAFADs=

Comment: Depending on [backwards compatibility needs](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_text-decoration-style_wavy), it may also be a possibility to use `text-decoration: wavy` (see [an example at css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration/).

Answer (score 34):

Below is an example of one of the ways that you can achieve that without an image. Adjust as needed.

```css
.err {
  border-bottom:2px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

}

.err:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom:2px dotted red;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 15px; /* Must be font-size minus one (16px - 1px) */
  left: -2px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;

  
  }
```

```html
<div>A boy whose name was Peter was <div class="err">woking</div> down the street</div>
```

Comment: Smooth, very good. Now thats thinking outside the box. +1

Comment: @Ruddy It's basicaly the same approach as this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6821456/1811992

Comment: @web-tiki Ah I see its just neater as its not inline CSS and using a pseudo element. Still very nice to see, didn't think of this method.

Comment: why do both the `.err` and `.err:after` rules have bottom borders?

Comment: @Jason S: If either of the two does not have bottom borders, it will just look like dots.

Comment: I've taken this and made it font-size agnostic, if anyone is interested: https://codepen.io/hyrumwhite/pen/MQLbjP

Comment: The best solution. Works excellent. I changed it a bit to avoid using non-relevant constants and styles (for example, display: is not required and top: should be replaced to bottom:) and it is exactly what I need. For example, Google uses background image which is less useful as it requires to add additional elements and they are blocks, so it is hard to <i>use in <span>mixed</i> mode</span>. text-decoration doesn't give what I need because the wave height is bigger and cannot be adjusted.

Answer (score 21):

You could use the CSS `text-decoration-style` property.

```
-webkit-text-decoration-style: wavy;
-moz-text-decoration-style: wavy;
text-decoration-style: wavy;
```

However, [this is limited to Firefox and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration). You may need to consider using a image instead.

Comment: This is now working in Chrome

Comment: @SethWhite - Have you got an example of this in Chrome as I can't get it to work.  <span style="-webkit-text-decoration-style: wavy;-moz-text-decoration-style: wavy;text-decoration-style: wavy;" >mistakes</span>

Comment: @SteveChilds sure: https://codepen.io/hyrumwhite/pen/exOQLy You just need to add text-decoration: underline, then apply the wavy style.

Comment: Looks like you can add `text-decoration-color: red` by now as well!

Comment: Great solution and works in Chrome: `text-decoration: underline wavy 1em red;`. You must use it with vendors too: **-webkit** and **-moz**

Comment: This works, but is quite ugly unfortunately.

Comment: Now working in all major browsers, correct CanIUse specific for "wavy" here: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_text-decoration-style_wavy

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `:after` pseudo-element on the link and set a repeat-x background of a wave image.
You can also use the `border-image` CSS3 property, but this is [not fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=border%20image) for old browsers