# CSS - Underline, strikethrough and overline (with styles and colors) in one element

Tags: html, css

I want to get **only one** `<span>` with three lines (underline, strikethrough and overline) like this: (That is only example, I want to change it dynamically)
[image]
but I can't use few `text-decorations` in one element like this:

```
span {
    text-decoration: overline dotted green;
    text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
    text-decoration: underline double red;
}
```

How can I do this using one `<span>`? Maybe I can use `::after` and `::before` or another languages like SASS or LESS?
Thanks for help.

Comment: <span>Some Text</span>

    span 
    {
        display:block;
        border-top:dotted 1px #000;
        border-bottom:thick double #ff0000;
        text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
    }

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do wavy underline with border

Comment: use text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua; as strike and the top and bottom line use  border;

Comment: Ok, but border don't have `wavy` style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` and `border-top` and `border-bottom` and `text-decoration`

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
  border-top:dotted 1px #000;
  border-bottom:thick double red;
  text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
```

**For the first comment**

```css
span{
  display:inline;
  text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
  font-size:22px;
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "Some Text";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: underline wavy red;
  z-index:-1;
  color:white;
}
 
span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "Some Text";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: overline wavy black;
  z-index:-1;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
```

**For the last comment**

```css
span{
  display:inline;
  text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
  font-size:22px;
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "S";
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
  text-decoration: underline wavy black;
  z-index:-1;
  color:white;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "S";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-decoration: underline wavy red;
  z-index:-1;
  color:white;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
```

Comment: This is not the answer because it does not work when text wraps.  If you keep this as the answer then people are going to continue to post this question over and over and you will continue to get duplicates.  moderator attention please.

Answer (score 6):

```css
span1 {
    text-decoration: line-through overline underline dotted green;;
}
span2 {
    text-decoration: line-through overline underline wavy aqua;
}
span3 {
    text-decoration: line-through overline underline double red;
}
```

```html
<span1>Some text</span1>
<span2>Some text</span2>
<span3>Some text</span3>
```

Comment: Example uses span1, span2, span3 but works with span.

Comment: this should have been the answer but you forgot to nest the spans. <span1><span2><span3>some text</span></span></span>

Answer (score 3):

Try using display block, and borders

```css
span{
  display:inline;
  border-top:dotted 5px #000;
  border-bottom:thick double #ff0000;
  text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
  font-size:5rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but `border` don't have 'wavy' style. What if i wanto to get wavy red underline and some strike and overline?

Comment: you can refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152175/a-wavy-underline-in-css

Answer (score 3):

Hope below code will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span1{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
span2{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
span3{
    text-decoration: overline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span3><span2><span1>sometext</span1></span2></span3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to use **only one**  `<span>`

Comment: It seems to not be possible with a single span.  This is absolutely the answer

Answer (score 2):

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: line-through overline underline;
  border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
  border-style: solid dashed dotted none;
  border-color: red green blue yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>Text decoration</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but border don't have 'wavy' style. What if i want to get wavy red underline and some strike and overline?

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```css
span:first-child{
  display:inline-block;
  border-top:dotted 1px #000;
  border-bottom:thick double #ff0000;
  text-decoration: line-through wavy aqua;
}
```

```html
<span>Some Text</span>
<span>Some Text</span>
<span>Some Text</span>
<span>Some Text</span>
<span>Some Text</span>
<span>Some Text</span>
```