# How to disable "selecting text" in my button

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have issue . I create pretty button but If I hover it , I can mark that text like on the photo? How I can fix that?

(im newbie).

Thanks

[My button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jlVF.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: Hi there solution with ::after selector. Check under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152175/a-wavy-underline-in-css

Answer (score 0):

```css
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>You should be able to select this text.</p>
<Button class="unselectable">Hey, you can't select this text!</Button>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me this way. My code: <input onclick="window.open ('http://xxxx/', 'nazwa');" type="submit1" value="Casual" align=right>

Comment: for submit button input type should be `submit` instead of `submit1`

Comment: I have already submit with other settings . What I should do If I want add new one?

Comment: This might work for you `<button type="submit1" class="unselectable" onclick="window.open ('xxxx/';, 'nazwa');" align=right>Casual</button>`

Comment: maybe other way. Why If I add class="test" to my input and add  .test { top:5000px; } in .css nothing happens ? ;/