# Wavy line in text field with CSS google like

Tags: css, textfield, underline

How is it possible to get the wavy line in a textfield in all browsers, like google?

[image]

Comment: In what context do you wish to achieve this line? Since this is clearly the wavy line that appears when you're making a typo

Comment: The same context like google. Its for a text correction

Comment: That's user sided.

Comment: The wavy line is created with css.

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a waved line under misspelled words HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821365/how-to-put-a-waved-line-under-misspelled-words-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google uses a repeated base64 encoded image as a span below the input. You can type stuff in your span and it will appear below it.

```css
.error:hover {
    background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAEAMIEAP9BGP6pl//Wy/7//P///////////////yH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAKAAQAAAMROCOhK0oA0MIUMmTAZhsWBCYAOw==) repeat-x scroll 0 100% transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
 }
```

```html
<span class="error">hello</span>
```

Disclaimer: You have to hover over the span for the effect to appear.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/wavy-unerline/);

With Content:

```
 .underline:after {
  content: '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  top:100%;
  margin-top: -.25em;
  letter-spacing:-.25em;
}
```

or with image:

```
.underline {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/HlfA2is.gif) bottom repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) and [`text-decoration-skip-ink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink).

The `text-decoration-skip-ink: none;` can be drawn across the full length of the text content.

```css
span {
  text-decoration: red wavy underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

```html
<span>asdsdfsf</span>
```